# Unable to Change Signature (v6.1)

Tags: resharper

It appears that I am unable to perform the `Change Signature` option in Resharper (v6.1).  This is the first time I've used it so I wasn't sure if I needed to enable something.

Whenever I right click on the method name I only have 2 options.  `Refactor This...` and `Rename...`.

I want to be able to change the signature but the option is not available to me.

Any ideas?

#### Additional Information

Visual Studio 2010 (v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel)
C#

Below is the method I am attempting to change the signature on.  This is a method in a base class.  I have highlighted the method name (`ConfirmPick`) and right clicked on it to attempt to change the signature.

```
public ExactaResult ConfirmPick(Guid locationId, decimal quantityPicked, bool isFullContainer = false)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough info. What language are you trying to invoke Change Signature in? What version of VS are you using? Can you show a piece of code and the caret position where you're trying to do that?

Comment: @gorohoroh I've added the additional information.

Comment: What do you see when you select `Refactor This...` ?

Comment: @AakashM There is one option that comes up: `Rename Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R`

Comment: Click _in_ the method name, don't select it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Selecting the method name was the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting (highlighting) a method name before trying to invoke a refactoring option. If you try do look at available refactoring options without selecting a method name, you'll see that there are plenty of them.
Also, I suggest that you use a ReSharper shortcut that shows all contextually available refactorings - Refactor This (Ctrl+R,R or Ctrl+Shift+R, depending on a selected keymap)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like selecting method name to perform *Change Signature* is more intuitive. While the right way is to right click on the method name without selecting it as @John Saunders said in the comments.